# Ortho effect and the relative acidity in aromatic acids

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, hyperconjugation, inductive-effect

[image: 2-methyl benzoic acid][image: 2-isopropyl benzoic acid]

What is the order of the acidity of 2-methyl benzoic acid and 2-isopropyl benzoic acid?
I know about ortho effect which states that the acidity of ortho- substituted aromatic carboxylic acids is greater due to stearic influences of the ortho substituent.Thus the two are probably more acidic than benzoic acid

Coming to the relative comparison , both groups show hyperconjugative effect as well as +I effect . The +I effect of -CH3 is less than that of isopropyl group whereas the hyperconjugative effect of isopropyl group is less than -CH3 group.As hyperconjugation is stronger, 2-isopropyl benzoic acid will be stronger than 2-methyl benzoic acid.
Is my reasoning correct? Or am I going wrong somewhere?